# What's the benefits from this kind of violation of the single responsibility principle

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

This code has been taken from `org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2` project, like the method name indicate, `createHttpServer` should be responsible **"only"** for creating and returning an instance of the `HttpServer` class, I just wonder why should the `HttpServer.start` call be encapsulated in such way ?

```
public static HttpServer createHttpServer(final URI uri,
                                              final GrizzlyHttpContainer handler,
                                              final boolean secure,
                                              final SSLEngineConfigurator sslEngineConfigurator
                                              final boolean start) {

        final String host = (uri.getHost() == null) ? NetworkListener.DEFAULT_NETWORK_HOST : uri.getHost();
        final int port = (uri.getPort() == -1) ? DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT : uri.getPort();

        final NetworkListener listener = new NetworkListener("grizzly", host, port);
        listener.setSecure(secure);
        if (sslEngineConfigurator != null) {
            listener.setSSLEngineConfig(sslEngineConfigurator);
        }

        final HttpServer server = new HttpServer();
        server.addListener(listener);

        // Map the path to the processor.
        final ServerConfiguration config = server.getServerConfiguration();
        if (handler != null) {
            config.addHttpHandler(handler, uri.getPath());
        }

        config.setPassTraceRequest(true);

        if (start) {
            try {
                // Start the server.
                server.start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new ProcessingException(LocalizationMessages.FAILED_TO_START_SERVER(ex.getMessage()), ex);
            }
        }

        return server;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### This is a public API method, not a class.

[**Single responsibility principle** in wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) says

> Every class should have a single responsibility, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class.

SRP is intended for loose coupling and robustness. It definitely helps **developers** in maintaining the same while keeping it well functioning.

So had it been some internal method or class, I would have agreed.

---

The design goals of public API are completely different.

- First thing you have to make sure about is **ease of use**.
- Your software should **hide internal** idiosyncrasies of the **implementation and design** as well.
- If a user is calling this method, and is unaware of requirement to call other method for starting, he/she'd be confused. We can not force users to know entire workflow of the software i.e. calling each small step manually.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only advantage I see is that the user has to write less code. I totally disagree with this practice. If it says "create", then it should only create. Anyway, as far as its clearly specified in the documntation, it shoul be "ok" to do that... It's not the worst violation of the SRP I have seen...

Comment: No They didn't [javadocs](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.7/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/grizzly2/httpserver/GrizzlyHttpServerFactory.html#createHttpServer(java.net.URI)), look at the code yourself.